# How is the range function defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Typing `help(range)` gives:

```
class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
```

Basically, I'd like to define a similar function, where the required parameter (stop) comes after the optional (start) unless you specify multiple (overloaded). How can this be done?

For example, how when you call:

```
# first (and only) param is stop
range(5)
# first param is start, second is stop
range(1, 5)
```

Comment: Something like `if stop is None: start, stop = 0, start`?

Comment: Since built-in functions, including range, cannot take keyword arguments (such as `range(stop=5)`), the closest solution would be variable-length arguments.

Comment: You can always look at the source of cpython. Looks like they basically see how many arguments were passed and act accordingly: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/580f357c663bd704a0903e4174cdf458cac56416/Objects/rangeobject.c#L77

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do this simply with the help of *args, for your case:-

```
class Range:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        if len(args)==1:
            start,stop,step=0,args[0],1
        if len(args)==2:
            start,stop,step=args[0],args[1],1
        if len(args)==3:
            start,stop,step=args[0],args[1],args[2]
```